# Android: Can't toggle MenuItem icon

Tags: android, menuitem

I'm tring to change a menuitem icon, but the icon is not being changed.

Here is how I find the MenuItem (works fine):

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu items for use in the action bar
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.activity_location_actions, menu);
    mActionLocation = menu.findItem(R.id.action_location);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

**Method UpdateIcon:** I took a screenshot so you can see (in the red frame) that the images have been found by the system.

[image]

The `mActionLocation` is a MenuItem which is initialized before this Method is called and is not null.

Anyone has an idea?

---

**UPDATE (solution by help from *@vinitius*)**

The UpdateIcon method:

```
private void UpdateIcon(boolean locationOn) {
    mActionLocation = locationOn; // mActionLocation is a global boolean
    invalidateOptionsMenu();
}
```

The onPrepareOptionsMenu override:

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Toggle location icon
    if (mActionLocation) {
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_location).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_location_on_white_24dp);
    } else {
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_location).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_location_off_white_24dp);
    }
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Comment: Great Answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPrepareOptionsMenu%28android.view.Menu%29):

> This is called right before the menu is shown, every time it is shown.You can use this method to efficiently enable/disable items or otherwise dynamically modify the contents.

Inside this method, retrieve your item as you do in `onCreateOtionsMenu` and check whether your gps in os or not to modify your item icon.

Comment: The basis for toggling this icon is not if the GPS is on or off, but rather if location tracking is on or off. Sorry for the misconception (I'll update the screenshot). That's why I have to toggle this icon from a few places in the Activity based on some Map events. Any other ideas, please?

Comment: @Ambran Just do what you need to do in any part of your Activity, then call `InvalidateOptionsMenu()`. It will cause your menu to redraw and then check any special conditions inside `onPrepareOPtionsMenu()` to modify your items accordingly.

Comment: Sorry, but it doesn't work. I added `invalidateOptionsMenu()` after the if/else clause in the `UpdateIcon` method. I can see that it is being hit and also that the `setIcon` statements are hit, but nothing happens. What am I missing here?

Comment: you have to set the icon inside `onPrepareOptionsMenu()` method. Are you doing it?